# Rake Task doesn't load Model with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, paperclip, rake-task

In a rake task for production to migrate some assets I want to require a model that uses Paperclip. But I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x00000006c12680>
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_recor/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
/app/models/user.rb:74:in `<class:User>'
```

Line 74 declares the attachment:

```
has_attached_file :photo, styles: { original: '1024x1024>', s64: ["64x64#", "jpg"] },
:convert_options => { original: "-quality 85 -strip", s64: "-quality 85 -strip" },
processors: [:trimmer, :cropper], url: '/system/product/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
path: ':rails_root/public/system/product/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
```

from the Rakefile: lib/task/asset.rake

```
task :preload => :environment do
   require 'user'
end
```

I tried to `require 'paperclip'` before 'user', but it didn't help.

Comment: What do you have in the `line 74` of your `User` model?

Comment: @Pavan sorry, forgot to include it - it's the `has_attached_file` call for Paperclip

Comment: Do you have a `photo` attribute in your `users` table?

Comment: The application works in development, production and staging. It's only the rake task who cannot load the user model.
I have
    photo_file_name character varying(255),
    photo_content_type character varying(255),
    photo_file_size integer,
    photo_updated_at timestamp without time zone,
in the user table (using postgres, copied from current structure.sql)

Comment: it's not finding your Class type, so a includes/require is missing. The clue is here `#<Class:0x00000006c12680>`. Without seeing more code I cannot tell you exactly why.

Comment: The assets.rake Task file

`require "logger"

Thread.abort_on_exception = true
#namespace :anything_you_want do
  namespace :assets do
  end
#end`

If I remove the comments on anything_you_want it works

Comment: Any way why this would help? Maybe the namespace assets is already taken and shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to have beeen the unfourtune choice of namespace "assets", which seems to interfere with rails defining this namespace already. For anyone who ends here with a similiar question: Try changing the namespace to something unique and see if the error disappears :)